# Checkout for another user using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model, check-out

Can we checkout page to another user via CSOM? Or, first checkout the page and then change to whom it is checked out to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `CheckedOutUserId` and `CheckoutUser` fields are declared as `ReadOnly` ([Field.ReadOnlyField property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.readonlyfield%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is set to `True`), it values could not be updated via CSOM.

From the other hand [SP.File.checkOut() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not accept parameter for specifying the checkout user.

Therefore it does not seem possible to checkout file to another user.